# Hyperlink getting displayed in terms of code

Tags: powershell, hyperlink

I am trying to hyperlink the numbers that show up in my inbox through powershell script. But the hyperlink shows up as the code itself and not the desired clickable link.

```
$b = $b + @{Label='ID';Expression={'a href="http://fire.sync.net/show_bug.cgi?id="$Bug_Id">$(Bug_Id)</a>'}}
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($b)
```

In my mailbox it shows up as

http://fire.sync.net/show_bug.cgi?id'+'='+'Bug_id'>211

Expected - 211 to be clickable and direct to specified url.

Code for the hyperlink part -

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: gray;border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width: 1px; padding: 7px; border-style: solid;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width: 0px;}"
$b = $b + @{Label='ID';Expression={"<a href='http://fire.sync.net/show_bug.cgi?id=$Bug_Id'>$Bug_Id</a>"}}


[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($b)
$a = $a + "</style>"


$body = $DataSet.Tables[0] | Select $b,Status,Summary,Deadline | convertto-html -head $a |  out-string;
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try splatting your html. You can also include your stylesheet as part of your conversion to HTML by adding the `-Head` switch.

```
$head=@"<style>
TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color: gray;border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%;}
TH{border-width: 1px; padding: 7px; border-style: solid;}
TD{border-width: 0px;}
</style>

$body = @{Label='ID';Expression={"<a href='http://fire.sync.net/show_bug.cgi?id=$Bug_Id'>$Bug_Id</a>"}} | 
ConvertTo-HTML -Head $head | Out-String
"@
```

[This article](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2013/06/11/in-the-mail-part-2.aspx) has a nice explanation about sending rich formatted HTML emails.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
Expression={ "<a href='http://fire.sync.net/show_bug.cgi?id=$Bug_Id'>$Bug_Id</a>" }
```

You were also missing an opening `<` which I've included in my example.

Comment: That didn't help. :( Still the same problem.